# JAX-WS migration from weblogic 10.3.1 to 12.1.3 - Error EclipseLink-3002

Tags: java, weblogic, eclipselink

I'am trying to migrate jax-ws web services from weblogic 10.3.1 to weblogic 12.1.3.

I deployed the war on weblogic 12.1.3 (the same war as deployed on 10.3.1 and running well on it)

I got the following exception when calling the Web service :

`Exception [EclipseLink-3002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException`

I noticed that in my wsdl are missing several types, these missing types are replaces by xsd:anySimpleType. I use classes generated from XSD files using XJC ant task.
Is the problem from the generated classes from XSDs ?

Comment: See https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/509937/  or something like http://weblogictroubleshoot.blogspot.com/2014/11/exception-eclipselink-3002-eclipse.html. Check your version of EclipseLink. What is the rest of the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a workaround :

You can configure JAXB providers at application-Level instead of depending on your application server.

Check Oracle documentation below :

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24964/data_types.htm#WSGET347